# how to solve this syntax error in mssql procedure

Tags: sql, procedure

I got a error

> incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Already declared all variables

```
BEGIN
 CASE WHEN TEMPLATE_NAME =  'SUCCESS'
     SET @vBody = CASE  @VAR2
     WHEN 'InterfaceNo'
         THEN  REPLACE(@vBody, '#{InterfaceNo}', @b_InterfaceNo)
     WHEN 'AgentJobName'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{AgentJobName}', @b_AgentJobName)
     WHEN 'PackageID'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{PackageID}', @b_PackageID)
     WHEN 'PackageName'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{PackageName}', @b_PackageName)
     WHEN 'ExecutionInstanceGUID'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{ExecutionInstanceGUID}', @b_ExecutionInstanceGUID)
     WHEN 'ExecuteStartTime'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{ExecuteStartTime}', @b_ExecuteStartTime)
     WHEN 'SourceFilePath'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{SourceFilePath}', @b_SourceFilePath)
     WHEN 'SourceTableName'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{SourceTableName}', @b_SourceTableName)
     WHEN 'BackupFilePath'
         THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{BackupFilePath}', @b_BackupFilePath)
     WHEN 'DataOwner'   
          THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{DataOwner}', @b_DataOwner)
 END
```

Comment: You are missing `END` for `BEGIN` as well as  `CASE WHEN TEMPLATE_NAME =  'SUCCESS'
          THEN  @vBody =   @VAR2 ... Your all other cases `

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
        CASE WHEN TEMPLATE_NAME =  'SUCCESS'
                 THEN  @vBody  
             WHEN 'InterfaceNo'
                 THEN  REPLACE(@vBody, '#{InterfaceNo}', @b_InterfaceNo)
             WHEN 'AgentJobName'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{AgentJobName}', @b_AgentJobName)
             WHEN 'PackageID'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{PackageID}', @b_PackageID)
             WHEN 'PackageName'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{PackageName}', @b_PackageName)
             WHEN 'ExecutionInstanceGUID'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{ExecutionInstanceGUID}', @b_ExecutionInstanceGUID)
             WHEN 'ExecuteStartTime'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{ExecuteStartTime}', @b_ExecuteStartTime)
             WHEN 'SourceFilePath'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{SourceFilePath}', @b_SourceFilePath)
             WHEN 'SourceTableName'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{SourceTableName}', @b_SourceTableName)
             WHEN 'BackupFilePath'
                 THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{BackupFilePath}', @b_BackupFilePath)
             WHEN 'DataOwner'   
                  THEN REPLACE(@vBody, '#{DataOwner}', @b_DataOwner)
         END  AS RESULT
END
```

Comment: Then i got an error mesage that [incorrect syntax error near =]

Comment: @김민선 You need to select column in THEN. See edited answer

Comment: I solved problem thanks :)

Comment: @김민선 You solved by this answer?